# get objective-c pointer to textbox in ViewController:CDVViewController html

Tags: objective-c, cordova

I am writing a cordova, iOS app (I don't use phone gap) which loads a single html file in a ViewController : CDVViewController (cordova 2.5.0).  I have a text box in the html file. The html file lives in the ViewController.

My question is this: What expression do I use from within an event handler in the  ViewController.m file, which will evaluate to myTextBox, which lives in the html file?

My textbox looks like this:

```
<input type="text" id="myTextBox" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Use UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification instead of UIKeyboardWillShowNotification. This should allow you to access the object key.

Comment: Nope.  When I use that event in my NotificationCenter code above, handleKeyboardWillShow is never hit.  How's your cordova api knowledge?  I have a feeling that that event doesn't work cause my textbox is in the html in a ViewController:CDVViewController.

Comment: I have greatly simplified my question since this answer was offered. - not getting into the event stuff since it really doesn't matter.